# Can a object property be passed as a function parameter

Tags: python, object

I am having trouble passing an object property as a function parameter in Python.

```
def selector_string(antique, field, variable):

     if antique.field == variable:

        return antique
```

The function above does not work if I pass in the relevant variables.

```
selector_string(item, 'country', 'SINGAPORE')

>>> Antique instance has no attribute 'field'
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Indentation, for sure :p

Comment: It simply doesn't work like this. My recommendation: Don't try and be "clever". If you mean `item.country`, just write that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), like this

```
if getattr(antique, field) == variable:
```

Quoting from the docs,

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, **getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar.** If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

If the attribute is not in the `antique` and if you want to provide a default value instead, you can do like this

```
if getattr(antique, field, None) == variable:
```

Here `None` is the default value returned, if the value of `field` is not there in `antique`.

If you want to know if the attribute really exists on the object, you can use [`hastattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) like this

```
if hasattr(antique, field):
    if getattr(antique, field) == variable:
        ...
        ...
else:
    print "Attribute '{}' not found in antique".format(field)
```

Comment: wrapping it in a `try, except` or using a default value will guard against `AttributeError`

Comment: @RedBaron Updated with the default value :)

Comment: Note, however, that most of the time, when you think you want to use `getattr`, what you *really* should be using is a dict.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible, but you can't just say `antique.field` because the program thinks you you are looking for an attribute called "field" instead of looking up an attribute whose name is *stored in* `field`. You can solve this by using the `getattr` function, which accepts a string containing the name of the field and returns the value of the field with that name:

```
def selector_string(antique, field, variable):

   if antique.getattr(field) == variable:
       return antique
```